# How to access my sites on IIS 7.5 from outside my network on Windows Server 2008

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm new to Windows Server 2008 and IIS, so please be patient.

I want to access my sites from outside my network.

I can browse my sites from the localhost, it's working.
I've added a binding to my site, Type: http, Host Name: www.dev.com, port: 80.
I have a static IP from my ISP, and my router is forwarding http requests to my server.
If I remove the Host Name and access directly using my network IP address, I get my site, but I want to provide a host name to the site because I'm going to add another web sites.
I've added www.dev.com to the DNS with my IP address.

What should I do next?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to what I was looking for, I should've done this:

create virtual application www.dev.com under default website on IIS,now I can access the website using STATIC_IP_ADDRESS/www.dev.com .